# How to add additional hours to pre-existing time in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to add additional hours to the pre-existing time. It works when I add with  DateTime.Now.AddHours(48) function... This add 48 hours to the current time.

But what I am not able to solve is adding the hours to the time from the past or future.

For example in the code below in "CheckInTime", I am trying to add 48 hours to the pre-existing time(not current time). The "CheckInTime" could be 9/14/2016 9:16:00 PM and I need to add 48 hours to that time. Which should be  9/16/2016 9:16:00 PM

This is a C# code.

```
DateTime? FutureTime;
DateTime? CheckInTime;

if (duration.Contains("48")) // duration is a time blocks (12 or 24 or 48)hrs
 {
   // add 48 hrs from current time
   FutureTime= DateTime.Now.AddHours(48); 

   // should add 48 hrs to the pre-existing time(past or future.)
   CheckInTime= GameSchedule.CheckInTime.AddHours(48); 
  }
  else if (...) // Other code...
  ....
```

What I want to get done: Add hours to the existing time(future or past).

EG:

```
CheckInTime= GameSchedule.CheckInTime.AddHours(48);
//where CheckinTime has past of future time. I want to add 48 hours.
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you have?

Comment: DateTime oldTime = DateTime.Parse("9/14/2016 9:16:00 PM");
            DateTime newTime = oldTime.AddHours(48);

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Please read the question carefully. To make it easier for you, I am not able to solve adding the hours to the time from the past or future.

Comment: @asax I've read the question carefully. *"I'm trying to add 48 hours to an existing DateTime"*. Ok, but what isn't working? What is the underlying problem? What are you seeing when you debug your code? Abstractly telling the problem isn't enough.

Comment: @asax: Yuval is (rightly) criticizing that you don't mention *what exactly goes wrong*. Do you get a compile-time error? If yes, which one? Do you get a run-time error? If yes, which one? Does `CheckInTime` contain the wrong result? If yes, which one?

Comment: When your code doesn't compile, and it doesn't, please start by reading the error message. If that doesn't help you, tell us what the error message is to make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CheckInTime` is a `DateTime?` - a [Nullable type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) - not a `DateTime`. Thus, you need to extract its `Value` first:

```
if (CheckInTime != null) 
{
    CheckInTime = CheckInTime.Value.AddHours(48);
}
else
{
    // Do whatever you want to do when CheckInTime has not been set yet.
}
```

Note: You can directly assign the result of `AddHours` (which is a `DateTime`) to `CheckInTime` (which is a `DateTime?`), because there is an implicit conversion from every ordinary type to its nullable type.

---

If you are using Roslyn or above, you can also use the `?.` operator instead of the `if` check:

```
// Yields null if CheckInTime is null; otherwise, yields the result of the method
// invocation.
CheckInTime = CheckInTime?.AddHours(48);
```

Comment: But is `GameSchedule.CheckInTime` nullable? Because he's trying to mutate an existing value and it doesn't look like it's nullable.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Impossible to say with the little information given in the question. I know I should have VTC'd and downvoted instead of answering, but sometimes I'm in the mood to make an educated guess.

Comment: Totally fair, we all have these moods :)